# Woocommerce - how to tell if product post has variations or not

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to edit the short-description template to be different on variable (single) product pages than on simple products. the code in that page is here:

```
global $post;
if ( ! $post->post_excerpt )
    return;
?>
<div itemprop="description">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
</div>
```

I want to add some code to the if statement that will be something like

**if post has variations, don't display short description, if simple product DO display**

but I can't find any way in the code to distinguish between a regular simple product post and one that is variable (has variations). And looking through the API docs over at the Woo site (http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/) I found nothing of that sort.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After much heartache, I have found the following two solutions:

In the product loop, you can use this:

```
 if( $product->has_child() ) {
```

but for some reason in the short description on the single product page, I had to use this:

```
global $post;
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
if( count( $children ) !== 0 ) {
```

Hope this helps others that were struggling as I was...

Comment: Actually, I figured out how to make the has_child tag work on the single product page as well, I needed to add a special global:

`global $post, $product, $woocommerce_loop;

 if( $product->has_child() ) { `

Comment: Thank you for your solution, this has helped me too.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this saved me a lot of hunting around the internet!!

Answer (score 104):

Use `$product->is_type()` function to check the product type. To check if the product is a variable product use:

```
global $product;

// $product->is_type( $type ) checks the product type, string/array $type ( 'simple', 'grouped', 'variable', 'external' ), returns boolean

if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {}
```

> There is also `$product->get_type()` function that returns the internal type of a product as a string.

Comment: And there is another type for products named `variation` which is a single child of a variable product and its useful if you want to access or edit fields of each variation for variable products in a loop.

Comment: @MojtabaRezaeian Does It mean that if I get the product from the line item of an order `$item->get_product()` then the type would be `variation`?

Comment: Downvote Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on null in

Answer (score 10):

Variable product always is based on [WC_Product_Variable](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product-Variable.html) class. E.g. [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions) follows this approach.

So, the checking can be:

```
is_a( $product, 'WC_Product_Variable' )
```

This ensures that the type of product is variable regardless of the presence of children. And it's fast.

Comment: Excellent solution. Theme developers should use it or get_type depending on the situation.

Comment: Yes, and note, that get_type returns different types depend on particular derived implementation, e.g. WC_Product_Variable_Subscription::get_type() returns 'variable-subscription' and WC_Product_Variable::get_type() returns 'variable'. So to check for variability we need to compare all possible variable types that may be not so convenient and universal in general checking.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason if you have deleted your variation, the has_child() function it still turns true.

So I used the below solution

```
if(empty($product->get_available_variations())) {
  // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_available_variations() on null

Comment: It looks like you are not getting the product right, or your product does not exits.
Maybe for testing purposes you can use `$product = wc_get_product(ENTER_A_PRODUCT_ID_IN_HERE);`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for me, using on `body_class` filter:

```
if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {

    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        ...
    }

}
```